# In Mongodb, how do I push a value into an array?

Tags: mongodb, database

Let's say my document is this:

```
{ names: ['jacob','jessie','andrew'] }
```

I want to push "michael" to all the documents. How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
db.mycol.update( {}, { $push : { names : "michael" } }, false, true );
```

Check out the [official docs on Updating](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-update%28%29) for more info, the general syntax is:

*db.collection.update( criteria, objNew, upsert, multi )*

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked [this](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-%24push) document?

```
db.your_collection.update({your_documents} { $push : { name : "michel" }})
```